# Why should the heating coil of a heater have high resistance?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

In my book, it is given:

> The resistivity of an alloy is generally higher than that of its constituent metals. Alloys do not oxidise (burn) readily at high temperatures. For this reason, they are commonly used
> in electrical heating devices, like electric irons, toasters etc.

If we want more heat, shouldn't we want more current to flow through the conductor (From the relation $H = VI$, Voltage constant in household circuits)? In that case, the resistance should be minimised?

However, my book says alloys are preferred because of their comparatively higher resistance.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In that case, the resistance should be minimised?

Yes, but

1. You don't want the heater element to produce so much heat that it melts itself.
2. You don't want the heater element to draw more current than the power source can support (i.e. you don't want to throw a breaker or start a fire in the building wiring).
3. Given the above constraints (or some other reason to choose a specific power consumption for your heater) you want to physically fit the heater in a reasonable amount of space. You can make a, for example, 10 ohm heating element with either 100 meters of "wire" that has 0.1 ohms per meter resistance, or with 1 meter of "wire" that has 10 ohm per meter resistance. The heater made with the second wire can be fit under your desk to keep your feet warm, the other one might be as big as your refrigerator. Which one do you think customers are more likely to buy?